# django taggit-serializer not create tags in rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

here is my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="post")
    title=models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    rate=models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)],default=True,null=True,blank=True)

    # rating=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    review=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    url=models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,related_name="post_voters")
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

in my serializers.py
i have imported

```
from taggit_serializer.serializers import (TagListSerializerField,
                                           TaggitSerializer)
```

and here is the post serializer

```
class Spost(serializers.ModelSerializer,TaggitSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()

    author=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    # likes_count=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # user_has_voted=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    ## for string related field without displaying it as numerics , it displays the direct object of that object"
    # user=Scomments()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','rate','author','content','review','url','tags')
    def get_likes_count(self,instance):
        return instance.voters.count()
    def get_user_has_voted(self,instance):
        request=self.context.get("request")
        return instance.voters.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()
```

but what issue i have been faceing right now is whenever i trigger a post request with tags the object is being created im getting that the object along with tags being created but when i see in the admin panel the tags part isnt being updated

```
{
        "rate": 4,
        "content": "content",
        "review": "dsfdf",
        "url": "http://google.com",
        "tags": [
            "django",
            "python"
        ]
    }
```

this is the post request and in postman i can see the updated request

```
{
    "id": 122,
    "title": null,
    "rate": 4,
    "author": "User",
    "content": "content",
    "review": "dsfdf",
    "url": "http://google.com",
    "tags": [
        "django",
        "python"
    ]
}
```

but when i see the same thing in django admin panel and json list of all objects i can see that tag part is blank

```
{
        "id": 122,
        "title": null,
        "rate": 4,
        "author": "User",
        "content": "content",
        "review": "dsfdf",
        "url": "http://google.com",
        "tags": []
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Spost(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
```

Here You have to pass `TaggitSerializer` as the first argument in your serializer. As you are inheriting the `TagListSerializerField` field from it.

Comment: Perfect ,issue sorted